# Android @Intdef for flags how to use it

Tags: android, android-annotations

I am not clear how to use @Intdef when making it a flag like this:

```
@IntDef(
  flag = true
  value = {NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD, NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST, NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS})
```

this example is straight from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html).  What does this actually mean ?  does it mean all of them are initially set to true ? if i do a "or" on the following:

```
NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD | NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST
```

what does it mean ...im a little confused whats happening here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the IntDef#flag() attribute set to true, multiple constants can be combined.

Users can combine the allowed constants with a flag (such as |, &, ^ ).

For example:

```
public static final int DISPLAY_OP_1 = 1;
public static final int DISPLAY_OP_2 = 1<<1;
public static final int DISPLAY_OP_3 = 1<<2;

@IntDef (
    flag=true,
    value={
            DISPLAY_OP_1,
            DISPLAY_OP_2,
            DISPLAY_OP_3
    }
)

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface DisplayOptions{}

public void setIntDefFlag(@DisplayOptions int ops) {
    ...
}
```

and Use `setIntDefFalg()` with '|'

```
setIntDefFlag(DisplayOptions.DISPLAY_OP1|DisplayOptions.DISPLAY_OP2);
```